# Using SQL to get a count of tickets done in a week? (Automated to run every week)

Tags: mysql, automation

I would like to use SQL on a dataset and would like to get a count of the total tickets each week.(The number is taken at the end of every week)
Is there any way in SQL to run a query that will automatically run every week and the current count will be stored in another dataset?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. The entity you're looking for is [`events`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html).

so your problem would be solved in following manner.

- Create another table, so that you can store the ticket counts by date or week.
- Create event and write `ticket count query` and corresponding `insert query to another table`.
- Set proper schedule to the event and you're done.

Still I would prefer to create a procedure and then call that [`procedure`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) inside the event rather than putting all logic inside event.